# Java Xpath with variables

Tags: java, xpath

I have this XML :

```
<rdf:RDF 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/">
<channel rdf:about="http://www.web.com/news.rss">
<items>
<rdf:Seq>
    <rdf:li resource="http://www.web.com/news1" />
    <rdf:li resource="http://www.web.com/news2" />
 </rdf:Seq>
</items>
</channel>
<item rdf:about="http://www.web.com/news1">
<title>my title</title>
<link>http://www.web.com/news1.html</link>
<description> bla bla </description>
</item>
<item rdf:about="http://www.web.com/news2">
<title>My Title 2</title>
<link>http://www.web.com/news2.html</link>
<description> bla bla 2 </description>
</item>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Here's my code to try to print title from each **rdf:li**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "Cp850")); 
    XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = parser.parse(args[0]);

   Element racine = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
       System.out.println("racine: "+ racine);
   NodeList nl = racine.getElementsByTagName("rdf:li");
for (int k = 0; k < nl.getLength(); ++k) {
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(k);
    String NewsTitle = e.getAttribute("resource");
         System.out.println("from :" + NewsTitle);
     String NoTitre = xPath.compile("//item[@rdf:about='" + NewsTitle + "']/title").evaluate(doc);
              System.out.println("Title : "+ NoTitre );

    }
}
```

Everything goes ok inside my loop, my NewsTitle variable gives me the good result.

My problem is my xpath.Compile is not good, I need help to know how to call my xpath to find the title for each news that will gives this result :

from : http://www.web.com/news1
**Title : bla bla**
from : http://www.web.com/news2
**Title : bla bla 2**

I'm not able to get the line in bold.(Title : bla bla)

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpath, Java and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885549/xpath-java-and-variables)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank I found finally by myself.
The Xpath need to remove the namespace rdf:
giving this :

```
String NoTitre = xPath.compile("//item[@about='" + NouvelleTitre + "']/title").evaluate(doc);
```