# Xpath, Java and variables

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Here is the code I currently have:

```
Document document2 = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("C:path to xml file.xml"));
Node theNode2 = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@name='**variable here**']", document2, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Where the code says "variable here", is it possible to search the XML file with a variable? I've only been able to hardcode in the thing I'm searching for so far ie :

```
("//*[@name='happy']", document2, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but i think what you want to be able to do is search for something but not hardcode this variable name?

```
String variable = "variable name";
Document document2 = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("C:path to xml file.xml"));
    Node theNode2 = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@name='" + variable+"']", document2, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create an instance of [`XPathVariableResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathVariableResolver.html) and attach it to your `XPath` instance.  There are unfortunately no standard implementations of this interface provided by default but it only contains one method so it's easy enough to implement yourself:

```
final Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
XPathVariableResolver varResolver = new XPathVariableResolver() {
  public Object resolveVariable(QName name) {
    // for simplicity, ignore namespaces
    return variables.get(name.getLocalPart());
  }
};
xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(varResolver);
```

With this in place you can now create variable bindings and refer to them in the XPath using `$var` syntax:

```
variables.put("theName", "happy");
Node theNode2 = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@name=$theName]", document2, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

This is much safer than trying to build up the XPath expression by concatenating different strings together, particularly if the value you want to use for `theName` comes from an untrusted source (this is the XPath equivalent of an SQL injection vulnerability).

For XPath there's the additional complication that while you can delimit a string literal with either single or double quotes there is no escaping mechanism, so it is impossible to have a single string literal in XPath that includes both single and double quote characters (you have to use a workaround like `concat('"', "'")`).  The variable resolver approach can handle this situation no problem:

```
variables.put("theName", "John \"The Boss\" O'Brien"); // escape " from Java
Node theNode2 = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@name=$theName]", document2, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Furthermore, now the actual XPath expression is a constant you can compile it once and then execute it multiple times against different variable values if you need to, rather than recompile it every time:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[@name=$theName]");
// look for @name='name 1'
variables.put("theName", "name 1");
Node node1 = expr.evaluate(document2, XPathConstants.NODE);
// look for @name='name 2' in the same document
variables.put("theName", "name 2");
Node node2 = expr.evaluate(document2, XPathConstants.NODE);
```